# Accessing AWS Secrets Manager from Docker

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services

All the tutorials I've seen for AWS Secrets Manager have secrets being retrieved by the CLI. How is this done in production?

Can I mount a set of secrets to a docker container as a file?

Answer (score 1):

> Access to AWS Secrets Manager requires AWS credentials. Those
>   credentials must have permissions to access the AWS resources that you
>   want to access, such as your Secrets Manager secrets. The following
>   sections provide details on how you can use AWS Identity and Access
>   Management (IAM) policies to help secure access to your secrets and
>   control who can access and administer them.

so you need to provide the `aws` credentials to docker which has access to the manger

you can follow on of these methods:

providing the credentials with `run` command:

```
docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXX -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXX myimage
```

or providing the file `~/.aws/credentials` and then create your container:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-open-port 8000 --amazonec2-region us-west-1 aws-sandbox
```

see [this](https://docs.docker.com/machine/examples/aws/)